# How to make center of line mark in proofreading?

Tags: tikz-pgf, proofreading

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
{\color{red}{$\sqsupset$}}a{\color{red}{$\sqsubset$}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

My purpose is to do it with `tikz`. Can you help me fix it?

Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/403013/33075

Answer (score 2):

I don't really get why you want to do this in TikZ, you have a perfectly fine symbol right there, but here you go:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\centerofline[1]{%
  \tikz\draw[red] (0,1ex) -| (1ex,0) -- (0,0);%
  \kern.2ex\relax
  #1%
  \kern.2ex\relax
  \tikz\draw[red] (1ex,1ex) -| (0,0) -- (1ex,0);%
}
\begin{document}

\small\centerofline{a}

\normalsize\centerofline{a}

\large\centerofline{a}

\Large\centerofline{a}

\end{document}
```

[image]